# Confusion with Exceptions in a simple login method. Do I even need them?

Tags: php, exception

So basically today I decided to test out using some exceptions in a simple login method because I have been reading about them for a while on loads of sites but when I start adding them into my code they just end up confusing me so today is hopefully the day I will find out what what I am doing wrong.

This is the login method (Just the validating input part, no database stuff or meaningful messages):

```
public function login($username, $password) {

    try {
        $this->security->validateInput($username, 'String', array(20, 6), 'username');
    }
    catch(InvalidArgumentException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    catch(LengthException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    catch(InvalidFormatException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

You can see from the catch blocks what exceptions the validateInput() method throws.

What I don't get is I have the $password variable to validate too but it just does not make sense to me to put it under the validation of the $username like:

```
try {
    $this->security->validateInput($username, 'String', array(20, 6), 'username');
    $this->security->validateInput($password, 'String', array(16, 8), 'password');
}
```

Am I using exceptions the complete wrong way and maybe they are not supposed to be used in login scripts and other similar scripts?

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: If you're taking the same action, no matter what the exception is, why catch all of the different kinds of exceptions? Why not just catch Exception?

Comment: I read here http://phpmaster.com/exceptional-exceptions/ and a few other places that you should rarely throw a new Exception, most of the time you should narrow it down to exceptions which extend the Exception class and are more unique to the problem. I couldn't tell you if it's right because I'm no exception expert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Define "need"

Whether or not you "need" to throw an exception in a particular case is probably something that is up for debate. Especially with loosely typed languages like PHP. If your interested on some of the arguments on when to use exceptions, you can mosey on over to [Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and see what they have to say on the topic. Specifically, you can take a look at the question [Defensive Programming Vs Exception Handling](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/139171/defensive-programming-vs-exception-handling). For the rest of my answer, I'm going to ignore whether or not you "need" to throw an exception, or even if it is the right thing to do. I'm going to do my best to leave correctness arguments aside and focus on your problem.

## Stumbling Through the Dark

So let's examine the problem. You are trying to login a user via a PHP script using OOP. First off, I'm sorry about that. OOP in PHP is terrible in my opinion. But, how to handle validation is something that really comes with a lot of personal preference, as well as situation. So, let's answer some questions first:

- **How are other scripts interacting with this?**
  An important thing to consider with validation is how other scripts are going to be interacting with this. If you are coding a simple login form for a website, and your validation only needs to occur on your login page, it can be easier to not worry about exceptions, but to simply show or redirect the user to a page indicating there was an error without logging them in. On the other hand, if you are needing to interact with this from multiple different pages, or sites, or in a manner in which a simple redirect isn't possible, it would probably be easier to throw an error and let the calling code figure out how to handle it.
- **Do you want to treat all exceptions differently?**
  For security reasons, you should not handle the username and password with different error messages. This gives an easy way to find out if a username is correct, and is a security issue (most of the time). Also don't say if they were "close". But, does that mean you want to handle invalid characters in a username the same? This is a place where exceptions can be useful, as it gives you the flexibility to distinguish errors, while still letting you process them the same if you want. It let's the calling code make that decision instead of having to do it in your validation.
- **Are other coders going to be using your code?**
  This is an important one for me. A descriptive exception and message can tell me what assumptions I did wrong, where as a cryptic return value, or a simple redirect I wasn't expecting can be frustrating. If you are trying to create a library, or code that will be reused elsewhere, you should throw descriptive exceptions. Also, have good documentation :)
- **How is your server configured to handle PHP exceptions?**
  If you are doing AJAX requests, or similar REST API requests, it can actually be useful to know how your server handles errors from PHP. Many are configured to just throw a "500 Server Error" for any unhandled exceptions. But some, especially if development settings are used, will show the error encountered and print the message. This can be useful when learning, but is poor practice for live sites. You'll want to make sure you are either handling all the exceptions you know about, or you'll want to give useful error messages that you are expecting on the other end.

## What Would I do?

With OOP, I always lean towards throwing exceptions rather than handling things using other methods. Exceptions allow things to be reused more easily since you are not reaching into other pieces of code to modify things. Objects should be independent so that you can use your objects again and again and again without having to rewrite it each time. This can be especially useful with things like login validation, since you will be able to fix any issues in 1 place, and you can continually improve it as you learn more.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I am going to keep on trying to learn them and implement them where need. The only problem is I find it very hard to find any good solid real life examples of it. Any articles I've read didn't give great real life examples which made it harder to follow.